# Help with map reduce in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I'm struggling to get a firm grasp of how map reduce works and when to use it. I'm getting some random results that just isn't making sense, but maybe my understanding of mapreduce in wrong?

Here's an example of what I am doing.

I have a collection of over 15000 uk towns with the following structure;

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e234105e138231a7f000004"),
  "county" : "Powys",
  "name" : "Abbey-Cwmhir",
  "location" : {
    "latitude" : 52.3298355191946,
    "longitude" : -3.39230306446552
  }
}
```

Each county has many towns, and I would like to get a new collection with the following structure for each county;

```
{
  "_id" : "Powys",
  "towns" : [
    {
      "name" : "Abbey-Cwmhir",
      "loc" : [52.3298355191946, -3.39230306446552]
    },
    //.. etc.
  ]
}
```

So, I guess map reduce is an ideal candidate for this right? If it is, how what would be the correct map and reduce functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point you could use something like this:

Map function

```
function() {
  emit( this.county,{ 
          towns: [ 
            { 
              name: this.name, 
              loc: this.location 
            }
          ]
        } ); 
}
```

Reduce function

```
function(key, values) {
  result = { towns: [] }; 
  values.forEach( 
    function( townsgroup ) {
      townsgroup.towns.forEach( 
        function( town ) {
          result.towns.push( town );
        });
    });
  return result;
}
```

Thank you dcrosta for the correction.

Comment: Return value of `reduce` should match the format of the emitted values: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-ReduceFunction

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what I was doing wrong but this example works! I'm going to study this until it clicks in my brain! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Kevin about the "what I was doing wrong" part: you were probably making the same mistake I did initially (until dcrosta corrected me), namely the reduce return value was not matching the format of the emitted values.

Comment: @dcrosta and Eugen: Please see my question, again on Map/Reduce and let me know how I can solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732735/query-in-a-mongodb-map-reduce-function. Thank you!