# Query in a MongoDB Map Reduce Function

Tags: java, mongodb, mapreduce

I have streamed and saved about 250k tweets into MongoDB and here, I am retrieving it, as you can see, based on a word, or keyword, present in the tweet.

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("TwitterData");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("publicTweets");
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject().append("tweet", 1).append("_id", 0);
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("tweet", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "autobiography"));
DBCursor cur=collection.find(query,fields);
```

What I would like to do is to use Map-Reduce and based on the keyword, categorize it and pass it to the reduce function to count the number of tweets under each category, kinda like what you can see [here](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/getting-mapreduce-working/). In the example, he's counting the number of pages as it is a simple number. I wanna do something like:

```
"if (this.tweet.contains("kword1")) "+
"category = 'kword1 tweets'; " + 
"else if (this.tweet.contains("kword2")) " + 
"category = 'kword2 tweets';
```

and then use the reduce function to get the count, just like in the sample program.

I know that the syntax is incorrect, but that's pretty much what I would like to do. Is there any way of achieving it? Thanks!

PS: Oh, and I'm coding in Java. So the Java syntax would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

The output of the code posted is something like this:

```
{ "tweet" : "An autobiography is a book that reveals nothing bad about its writer except his memory."}
{ "tweet" : "I refuse to read anything that's not real the only thing I've read since biff books is Jordan's autobiography #lol"}
{ "tweet" : "well we've had the 2012 publication of Ashley's Good Books, I predict 2013 will be seeing an autobiography ;)"}
```

This of course, is for all tweets with the word "autobiography". What I'd like is to use this in the map function, categorize it as a "autobiography tweet" (and other keywords too), and then send it to the reduce function to count everything and return the number of tweets with the word in it.

Something like:

```
{"_id" : "Autobiography Tweets" , "value" : { "publicTweets" : 3.0}}
{"_id" : "Biography Tweets" , "value" : { "publicTweets" : 15.0}}
```

Comment: If you can paste one of the document structures of what you have, and what you're looking for in your aggregated area it would be helpful to write the reduce function.

Comment: where are you hoping to get the Category (like Autobiography / Biography) values from? are those somewhere in the tweet object?

Comment: or are you hoping to grep through the tweet with a list of your keywords?

Comment: Grep. Like I said.. this.tweet.contains(keyword). Its more like a regex, I just wrote .contains to convey the idea.

Comment: how many keywords are you using here?

Comment: and is there a reason you don't want to just do something like db.publicTweets.count({tweet,/autobiography/i}) - run this query once per keyword for each keyword?  What does mapReduce gain you here?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: I could do that, but this is for a project and I just wanted to implement Map/Reduce for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: I see that you work at 10gen. I'm sure you'd be able to help me out! :)

Comment: Btw, the example you linked to is not correct (though syntactically it's close - just won't give the right answer).  I recommend looking here: cookbook.mongodb.org and also MapReduce documentation page and then if you still have trouble, post what you are getting and I'm sure we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to try the following:

```
    String map = "function() { " +
                 "    var regex1 = new RegExp('autobiography', 'i'); " +
                 "    var regex2 = new RegExp('book', 'i'); " +
                 "    if (regex1.test(this.tweet) ) " +
                 "         emit('Autobiography Tweet', 1); " +
                 "    else if (regex2.test(this.tweet) ) " +
                 "         emit('Book Tweet', 1); " +
                 "    else " +
                 "       emit('Uncategorized Tweet', 1); " +
                 "}";

    String reduce = "function(key, values) { " +
                    "    return Array.sum(values); " +
                    "}";

    MapReduceCommand cmd = new MapReduceCommand(collection, map, reduce,
             null, MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE, null);
    MapReduceOutput out = collection.mapReduce(cmd);

    try {
        for (DBObject o : out.results()) {

            System.out.println(o.toString());

       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Kay! I will try this out and let you know, with an approval, if this works or at least, comes close to working. Thank You! :)

Comment: Good answer. But I think this will recompile the regular expressions every time the map function is called. I wonder if it would be possible to solve this more efficiently.

Comment: I think you can use the 'scope' option to declare and define the regex variables.  Thanks also for your suggestion regarding the full text search in Mongo. Regards. ; )

Answer (score 5):

Although you already accepted the answer by Kay and this one will likely be ignored, I would like to suggest an alternative solution.

Th MongoDB documentation has an article about how to perform [full text search in Mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo). In order to allow text-based fields to be searched quickly for individual words, they suggest to prepare the documents by splitting the textfields into arrays of individual words, store these arrays in the documents together with the full text, and create an index over this array.

Afterwards you can very quickly find all documents which contain a specific word, because your search query can 1. use an index and 2. doesn't have to use a regular expression (which can be very expensive).

Comment: Not ignored. Duly noted and I've now learnt something new. Thanks!